# Version Control in Git - Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I’ve used other version control applications before whilst developing SSIS packages yet I’m working on an API and nodejs application at present and considering using bitbucket.

I had a look at it today and created a repository and started with some files.

My question is around the application I’ve onboarded it has a large Visual Studio solution for the API yet I can’t see how I’d get that onto bitbucket as a master. Returned 413 errors and I suspect it’s due to the size about 1GB.

My understanding of version control in the past scenario was that it would take all files so the entire application can be tracked.

Might be missing something… not sure?

Comment: Please add the steps you did and post the error messages you received. What tool are you using, what OS?

Comment: Git itself can handle this just fine, but a lot of hosting sites put size limits on hosted repositories so that people don't just store terabytes of data on them without paying. Bitbucket in particular have soft and hard limits: do a web search. Note that this is quite independent of http payload size limits: 413 is a payload size limit for a single http request, but you can interact with hosting sites using ssh instead of http(s).

Comment: This what I get when running on Windows in Git Bash. 

Counting objects: 23326, done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (36081/36081), done.
Writing objects: 100% (23326/23326), 483.30 MiB | 14.26 MiB/s, done.
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 413
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Total 23326 (delta 19498), reused 23304 (delta 19493)

I’ve tried the below but does the same.

git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `gitignore` file. You can setup git to ignore some files in your repo. Usually people do not include dependencies (like node modules) or generated binaries in the repo because they can get quite large and can be easily downloaded.

You can use website like `gitignore.io` to generate the file for you based on the project type.